# How can I get post text from all posts on a Wordpress news site?

Tags: posts, xml

I'm a Digital Operations manager for a college news site, and as part of a new project, I'm trying to generate a corpus of all article content we've released.

## Approaches I've considered thus far:

- Using a web scraper to retrieve all post content
- Using an XML parser to parse the site's post XML dump

What's the best methodology to do this? Any specific libraries you've found helpful?

I have admin privileges if that helps.

Comment: what are you generating to?  what is the end result?  Are you looking to just have a table in excel etc or individual pages in word or separate word files?

Answer (score 0):

Will using mysqldump get you the results that you want?

```
mysqldump -u username -p dbname wp_posts > myposts.sql
```

You will have to handle the images separately.